# Unity forward position = camera angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I am very new to Unity and only got basic knowledge. I created a player who can move and also a camera which follows the player and according to the mouseX and mouseY acis the camera rotates.
Now I want the camera rotation angle to be the forward position.

If the player press w he moves along x acis but if the camera angle change and the player press w it should move into this direction.
player.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoublePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController _controller;
    public float _jumpHeight = 3f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float _moveSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float _gravity = 9.81f;
    private float _directionY;
    void Start()
    {
        _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput);
        
        // set gravity
        _directionY -= _gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        direction.y = _directionY;

        _controller.Move(direction * _moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

camera.cs

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float RotationSpeed = 1;
    public Transform Target, Player;
    float mouseX, mouseY;
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        CamControl();
    }
    void CamControl()
    {
        mouseX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * RotationSpeed;
        mouseY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * RotationSpeed;
        mouseY = Mathf.Clamp(mouseY, -35, 60);

        transform.LookAt(Target);

        Target.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(mouseY, mouseX, 0);
        Player.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, mouseX, 0);
    }
}
```

For Target and Player variable I selected the player object.
Do someone has a simple solution I can understand?

Comment: Add - to invert your value: Target.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-mouseY, -mouseX, 0);

Comment: That doesnt change anything :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply take the `direction` and rotate it along with the object that component is attached to using [`Quaternion * Vector3` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html)

```
var rotatedDirection = transform.rotation * direction;
```

---

Or if you rather need the orientation of the other script attached to a different object then do e.g.

```
// link your camera or whatever shall be used for the orientation via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private Transform directionProvider;
```

and then

```
var rotatedDirection = directionProvider.rotation * direction;
```

Comment: Thaank that easy solution fixed my prolem :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're getting the rotation directly from a `Transform`, you could use [`Transform.TransformDirection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformDirection.html):

```
Vector3 rotatedDirection = transform.TransformDirection(direction);
```

Comment: I think it does basically `transform.rotation * direction` under the hood but of course why not use that method ;)